# Loss of session and application ended randomly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, global-asax, application-end

I have sessions recording a user's log in information but it gets lost due to my application ending.

Running my code from local host i have no issues, but now that i have lunched the site live i lose the session very quickly with in minutes.

I decided to log the Golbal.asax file and record when a session is started and ended and when my application starts and ends and if there are any application errors.

When a user navigates thought the website the session is checked if its null, if the session is not null i register hidden fields for that page to use my session values, but if the sessions are null i abandon them and redirect to my login page.

Here is what my log has shown me:

```
[11:52:25]   Application has started 
[11:52:25]   Session has started 
[11:52:35]   Use session 
[11:52:45]   Use session 
[11:52:54]   Use session 
[11:52:59]   Use session 
[11:53:5 ]   Use session 
[11:53:10]   Use session 
[11:53:15]   Use session 
[11:53:18]   Session has ended 
[11:53:18]   Application has ended 
[11:53:22]   Application has started 
[11:53:23]   Session has started 
[11:53:23]   Abandon Session 
[11:53:23]   Session has ended 
[11:53:23]   Session has started
```

I navigated around my site with 7 clicks on the same hyper link basically just refreshing the page i was on, but for an unknown reason the session was lost and application was ended. As you can see from the log, this was all within a minute.

When a navigation link is clicked this is the code to check the session.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        LogClass Log = new LogClass();

        if (this.Session != null && this.Session.Count > 0)
        {
            Log.Logger("Use session");

            string email = (string)this.Session["Email"];
            int practiceId = (int)this.Session["PracticeId"];
            int practitionerId = (int)this.Session["PractitionerId"];

            this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("loggedInUserName", email);
            this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("practiceId", practiceId.ToString());
            this.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("practitionerId", practitionerId.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Logger("Abandon Session");
            this.Session.Abandon();
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");  
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

What could be causing my session to get lost so quickly, and why is the just a problem when hosted live and not a problem from local host?

What causes the application to end, since i have no application errors logged?

Comment: Have a look in the application and system event logs on the server and see if there is anything related in there.

Comment: have you tried setting Session timeout?

Comment: @KT Yes i have raised the time out time, but even leaving it on its original setting of 20min it should still be fine, with the above example you can see the session was lost within a Minuit.

Comment: Have a look at the recycling conditions on your application pool in IIS. There might be something that triggers application pool recycling (Memory limit, number of requests, interval...)

Comment: I am facing same issues, have you got any solution for it? I am using shared normal server so I can not tough IIS.